# Delete Encrypted Couchbase Lite DB (Xamarin)

Tags: encryption, xamarin.android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm using Couchbase Lite for Xamarin (android) and I would like to delete an encrypted DB.
Here is my code to delete:

```
var databaseName = "XYZ";
var manager = Manager.SharedInstance;
manager.GetExistingDatabase(databaseName).Delete();
```

When I run this code I get:

> Couchbase.Lite.CouchbaseLiteException: Error 21, 26 (file is encrypted or is not a database) executing sql 'CREATE TABLE docs (         doc_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,         docid TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)'

I know the database exists and is encrypted.

The docs don't specify that deleting only works on unencrypted databases.
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/database/database/index.html

Is there a different way to delete an encrypted database?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is instead of

```
 manager.GetExistingDatabase(databaseName).Delete();
```

do

```
manager.DeleteDatabase(databaseName);
```

This allows for deletion of an encrypted couchbase lite DB without having the key.

Comment: The former also works, provided you have already opened it with the proper key.